# Json and Array serialization - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

Im trying to insert a list of phones with no success.

My Domain Client class

```
@Entity   
public class Client {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integir id;
private String name;
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(****)
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
**gets and sets**

   public Client (String name){
   this.name = name;
   }
}
```

My Domain Phone class

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integir id;
private String number;
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "phones")
private List<Client> clients = ArrayList<>();
**gets and sets**
    public Phone(String number) {
    this.number = number;
    }  
}
```

I have a DTO ClientDTO

```
public class ClientDTO {

private String name;
private String number;
private List<Phone> numbers = ArryList<>();
**gets and sets** 
}
```

My service ClientService hava this method:

```
public Client fromDTO (ClientDTO clientDTO) {

  Client c = new Client(clientDTO.getName());
  for(Phone p: clientDTO.getNumbers()) {
  p.setNumber(x.getNumber);
  p.getClients().addALL(Arrys.asList(c));
  c.getPhones().addAll(Arrys.asList(p));
  }
}
```

If i try to this in Postman:

```
{
 "name" : "Teste",
 "numbers": 
  [
   { "number" : "xxxxxx"},
   { "number" : "yyyyyyy"}  
  ]
}
```

Shows Error 415 : Unsupported Media Type

If i change my ClientDTO to:

```
public class ClientDTO {

private String name;
private String number;
**gets and sets** 
}
```

And my method in ClientService to:

```
public Client fromDTO (ClientDTO clientDTO) {

Client c = new Client(clientDTO.getName());
Phone p = new Phone(clientDTO.getPhone());

p.getClients().addAll(Arrys.asList(c));
c.getPhones().addAll(Arrays.asList(p));
}
```

And in my postman i send this:

```
{
  "name" : "Teste",
  "number": "xxxxx" 
}
```

Works fine.

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty(no-args) constructor to both Client and Phone entity classes

Client Entity Class

```
@Entity   
public class Client {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integir id;
private String name;
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(****)
private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
**gets and sets**

   public Client (){}
   public Client (String name){
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Phone Entity Class

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integir id;
private String number;
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "phones")
private List<Client> clients = ArrayList<>();
**gets and sets**

    public Phone() {}
    public Phone(String number) {
      this.number = number;
    }  
}
```

You can't serialize an object if it has no Serializable super-class and has no no-arg constructor. Since You used Phone entity class in ClientDTO and it has no no-arg constructor serialization process fails

Comment: I included the default constructor but the error persists. So i included the annotation @JsonIgnore on ClientDTO -> List<Phone> and the error ends. But no phone is included. And now? what im doing wrong?